# I cannot concatenate a variable + string + variable this line of code gives me a error "None of the following functions can called with the argument s

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm a newcomer in this, and I'm learning kotlin in android studio, and I'm stacked in this error, "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied" when I want to concatenate a variable + string + variable the error appears, and when delete the first variable and the plus signal the error disappears, Could anyone help me whit this? this is the part of the code

```
 /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    fun submitOrder(view: View?) {
        var price = quantity * 5
        var  priceMessage = price + "dollars for  " + quantity + " of coffee. Pay up"
        displayMessage(priceMessage)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try String Templates in Kotlin

String templates allow you to include variable references and expressions into strings. When the value of a string is requested, all references and expressions are substituted with actual values.

> Take this kotlin example. https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/08_productivity_boosters/02_String%20Templates

```
  fun submitOrder(view: View?) {
            var price = quantity * 5

              *// Templates try like this*
             var  priceMessage = "$price dollars for  $quantity of 
              coffee. Pay up"
                        (or)
             *//(you can execute command inside like this)*
             var  priceMessage = "${String.format("%.3f", price)} dollars 
             for  ${quantity+1} of coffee. Pay up"


            displayMessage(priceMessage)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`price + "dollars for  "` won't work because you can't add a string to a number. If you want to concatenate them all, you can do like this using [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-templates):

```kotlin
val priceMessage = "$price dollars for $quantity of coffee. Pay up"
```